# Setting Profile picture (PhotoUrl) working in Unity, but not in Android build

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Firebase, been struggling with this one for days and would really appreciate some help.

I'm setting the DisplayName and PhotoUrl properties of a new account and then immediately retrieving them in the console. In Unity everything works fine

This code returns the username and Uri when I do Debug.Log(), but once built logcat tells me the DisplayName has been set correctly, but PhotoUrl is Null:

```html
 public void UpdateUser()
 {
  user = auth.CurrentUser;

  if (user != null) {
  Firebase.Auth.UserProfile profile = new Firebase.Auth.UserProfile {
   DisplayName = "Jane Q. User",
   PhotoUrl = new System.Uri("https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/95.jpg")
  };
  user.UpdateUserProfileAsync(profile).ContinueWith(task => {
   if (task.IsCanceled) {
       Debug.LogError("UpdateUserProfileAsync was canceled.");
       return;
   }
   if (task.IsFaulted) {
       Debug.LogError("UpdateUserProfileAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
       return;
   }
   User = auth.CurrentUser;
   Debug.Log(user.DisplayName);
   Debug.Log(user.PhotoUrl);

   Debug.Log("User profile updated successfully.");

   userProfile.GetProfile();
  });
 }
```

Sorry if I missed something in the documentation, I really did scour it for answers but I'm just coming up empty handed, and I'm getting no errors to indicate the problem. Would appreciate any ideas!

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I have tried setting rules in storage to get a UID for authentication. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue for Android.

```
private string userProfileImage;
public Image profileImg;
private IEnumerator PlayerImage()
{
    userProfileImage = FindObjectOfType<Authentication>().userPhotoUrl;
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(userProfileImage))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        profileImg.sprite = Sprite.Create(DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr),new Rect(0f, 0f, DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr).width, DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr).height), new Vector2(0f, 0f));
    }
}
```